# How to pass a value from JSON to a command in shell script at Docker?

Tags: shell, sh

I have a dockerfile to create an image with Ubuntu 16.04. Inside the docker file:

```
# dotnet tool command
RUN apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2 -y
# for dot net tool
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"
# jq command to read json file
RUN apt-get install jq -y
ADD xxx /xxx
# Copy the deploy-tool.json file
ADD deploy-tool.json /xxx/deploy-tool.json
# Copy the main sh script to xxx
ADD main-migrate.sh /xxx/main-migrate.sh
# Run the main sh script to run script in each xxx/*/bla..bla.sh 
RUN chmod +x /xxx/main-migrate.sh
RUN /permasense/main-migrate.sh
```

my `deploy-tool.json` is as followed:

```
{
    "name": "xxx.DEPLOY",
    "version": "1.2.3-dev.29"
}
```

here is `main-migrate.sh`

```
name = $(jq '.name' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)
nugetFileVersion = $(jq '.version' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)

# TODO how to pass value from JSON to the command below
# install dot net nuget
dotnet tool install -g $name --version "$nugetFileVersion" --add-source /xxx/
```

I have the `xxx.DEPLOY.nupkg` in `xxx` folder.

When `dockerfile` runs `main-migrate.sh`, I got error message complaining that the `name` and `nugetFileVersion` cannot be found.

How do I pass `name` & `nugetFileVersion` from the `jq` command to the `dotnet tool install` above as shown in `main-migrate.sh`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is right, but the problem is with your `main-migrate.sh` script in the assignment statements. Shell assignments don't take spaces around the `=` symbol. It should have been

```
name=$(jq '.name' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)
#  ^^^ no spaces
nugetFileVersion=$(jq '.version' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)
#              ^^^ no spaces
```