# How to pass version number from jq for dotnet tool install command in Ubuntu?

Tags: .net, shell, sh, ubuntu-16.04, jq

This question is related to my previous question here:
[How to pass a value from JSON to a command in shell script at Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818783/how-to-pass-a-value-from-json-to-a-command-in-shell-script-at-docker?noredirect=1#comment102068283_57818783)

I have a shell script file as below:

```
name=$(jq '.name' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)
nugetFileVersion=$(jq '.version' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)
#bash
#echo $name

# TODO how to pass value from JSON to the command below
# install dot net nuget
dotnet tool install -g $name --version $nugetFileVersion --add-source /xxx/
```

Here is my `deploy-tool.json` file

```
{
    "name": "xxx.DEPLOY",
    "version": "1.2.0-dev.29"
}
```

When I run the script above in the dockerfile, I got an error message saying:

> Specified version '"1.2.0-dev.29"' is not a valid NuGet version range.

I tried to check `dotnet-tool install` documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install
However, I could not find anything useful.

How do I pass the `nugetFileVersion` from the `jq` command to the `dotnet tool install`'s version parameter like how I managed to do so in powershell like the image below:
[image: powershell command OK]

Thank you

Comment: your version number is double quoted. Try 
`name=$(jq -r '.name' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)`
`nugetFileVersion=$(jq -r '.version' /xxx/deploy-tool.json)`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `jq .version` you get the output `"1.2.0-dev.29"`. You need it without the quotes. To get that, add `-r` (`--raw-output`) to your jq call:

```
jq -r '.version' yourfile
```